# How to read byte value from databricks secret scope

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have been experimenting with using different encryption methods and storing keys in Databricks secret scope.

I have been trying to implement this: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.AESGCM

So I run:

```
key = AESGCM.generate_key(bit_length=128)
```

The operation above returns bytes (example: b'dfh576748') Then I store this value into secret scope, it keeps complaining it is not byte value when I run:

```
aesgcm = AESGCM(key)
```

I have tried to put secret in a variety of ways including using 'binary-file' flag when saving the secret via Databricks CLI & when reading it flagging readBytes etc, it seems I can't store a byte in the secret scope and read it back?

Answer (score 0):

A way around this was to run:

```
encrypt_value = AESGCM.generate_key(bit_length=256)

# Pass "wb" to write a new file, or "ab" to append
with open("test.txt", "wb") as binary_file:
    # Write text or bytes to the file
    binary_file.write(encrypt_value)
```

then run:

```
databricks secrets put --scope test-encrypt --key test5 --binary-file test/test.txt
```

pull secret by using:

```
dbutils.secrets.getBytes
```